# Solution to cigars and squirrels puzzle on CodingBat throws syntax error

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax-error

I am trying to solve [this](http://codingbat.com/prob/p159531) CodingBat problem:

> Squirrels who like to party get together and smoke cigars. Such a party is only deemed successful when the number of cigars is between 40 and 60, on a weekday. On weekends, however, there is no upper bound on number of cigars. Write a function that returns True if the party with the given values was successful.

Unfortunately, although I have used Python occasionally, I am not good enough at it to understand why my code fails with a syntax error on line 5:

```
def cigar_party(cigars, is_weekend):
  if is_weekend:
    if cigars >= 40:
      return True
  else if:
    cigars >= 40 and cigars =< 60:
      return True
  else:
    return False
```

Comment: One more note: In Python (unlike most languages), you can write `40 <= cigars <= 60` instead of `cigars >= 40 and cigars <= 60`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python you need to use `elif` instead of `else if`.

More information:
http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html

Also change the following line:

```
else if:
cigars >= 40 and cigars =< 60:
```

To this:

```
elif cigars >= 40 and cigars <= 60:
    return True
```

The less than or equal to sign needs to be `<=` and there should not be a colon between the keyword elif and the rest of the expression.

Comment: Also, thanks for asking this.  I finally got to answer my first question! :)

Comment: great. the codingbat question is not correct, but the error's sorted. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as tcdowney pointed out, the syntax is elif, not else if, secondly, you need to have the logical assessent in the elif statement, not as some sort of operation. Lastly, have the greaterthan/smallerthan sign before the equals sign.

```
elif cigars >= 40 and cigars <= 60:
    return True
```

That should do the trick ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
def cigar_party(cigars, is_weekend):
  a = range(61)
  if is_weekend and cigars not in a:
    return True

  elif cigars in range(40,61):
    return True

  else:
    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def cigar_party(cigars, is_weekend):
   if is_weekend and cigars>=40:
     return True
   elif not is_weekend and cigars in range(40,61):
     return True
   return False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def cigar_party(cigars, is_weekend):
    if is_weekend:
        return cigars >= 40
    return 40 <= cigars <= 60  // Python supports this type of Boolean evaluation
```

or using the ternary form:

```
def cigar_party(cigars, is_weekend):
    return cigars >= 40 if is_weekend else 40 <= cigars <= 60
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def cigar_party(cigars, is_weekend):
  if is_weekend:
    if cigars>=40:
      return is_weekend
  else:
    if cigars in range(40,61):
      return True
  return False
```

Comment: Please add explanation

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 0):

```
def cigar_party(cigars, is_weekend):
  if is_weekend == True:
    if cigars >= 40:
      return True
    else:
      return False
  if is_weekend == False:
    if cigars >= 40 and cigars <= 60:
      return True
    else:
      return False
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

```py
#got 9/12 not bad! 

is_weekday = True
is_weekend = True 


def cigar_party(cigars, is_weekend):
    if is_weekend and cigars >= 0: 
        return True 
    elif is_weekday and cigars >= 40: 
        return True 
    else: 
        return False
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def cigar_party(cigars, is_weekend):
  if is_weekend and cigars >= 40:
      return True
  elif cigars >= 40 and cigars <= 60:
      return True
  else:
    return False
```